# block url in IPSec Policies on local computer

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, ip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGAdj.jpg) In my app i want to block an IP in IPsec Policies. and this is main part of blocking code:

```
public static void BlockIpAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    string policyName = "Block_" + ipAddress; // Descriptive policy name

    try
    {
        // Create a new IPSecurityPolicy object
        var ipSecurityPolicy = new IPSecurityPolicy(policyName);

        // Add a filter rule to block the specified IP address
        var filter = new IpFilterRule(address: ipAddress, mask: "255.255.255.255", direction: SecurityRuleDirection.Inbound);  // Block inbound traffic
        ipSecurityPolicy.AddFilter(filter);

        // Set the action for the filter rule (Block connection)
        ipSecurityPolicy.AddMatchingRule(new IPSecurityRule(filter: filter, action: SecurityAction.Block));

        // Assign the policy to the local computer
        ipSecurityPolicy.Assign();

        Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0} blocked successfully using policy: {1}", ipAddress, policyName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error blocking IP address: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

in my app I am using System.Security.Cryptography, but visual stodio flags it as unnecessary. and the "IpFilterRul", "IPSecurityRule" "SecurityRuleDirection", "IPSecurityPolicy" could not be foun. which directive I have to use? or which assembly reference I should add?. give me complete solution please. thanks all.

I added to many directives but none of them working...

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows firewall? Where did you get this code from? It looks like it might be for Azure Firewall but hard to say.

Comment: How could write code using an API for which you have no documentation?

Comment: @Charlieface No I am talking about IP Security Policies on Local Computers. run secpol.msc in windows.

Comment: Looks like Powershell might be a good start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netipsecrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps and you can use `Powershell.Create` to run scripts and commands direct from C# (without going out to powershell.exe)

Comment: Asking for a complete solution is usually not appreciated but I understand why you ask for it.