# controlling IP Security Policies on windows

Tags: c#, .net, security, ip

Does any one knows how can I Create new IP security Policy by C# Code? [See picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l1Ze.jpg) I Used powershell or System.Securuty.cryptography but I could not achieve wat I want. any solution?

Comment: Please don't post the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78141196/10024425)  more than once.